# Use "AspNetCore" in a netstandard2.0 library

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I'm writing a nuget package targetting both net6.0 and netstandard2.0.
Inside I need to use WebApplication (and other stuff found in AspNetCore which works with net6.0).
In net6.0 i use

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

How can I use these objects when compiling in netstandard2.0 ? I can't find the packages to use for that.

So basically, how do I use the AspNetCode services inside a netstandard2.0 library ?

**Edit to clarify the subject**

I actually have a .net core app running in a console, using websocket and http resources. That app needs to run in a windows service which is a .net framework solution. I understand I can't use AspNetCore but can't find a way to use anything else and nuget is populated with so many deprecated packages I don't know what to use here. Could it be AspNet ? Then how do I identify the necessary packages I need according to the uses described above (I must be dumb here not being able to do it)

Comment: Do you mean "AspNetCore" when you write "AspNetCode"? As far as I know if you intend to write code that implements a web host, you need to choose AspNet from 4.8 or AspNetCore. I think you should be more specific here about what exactly you need to do. You may want to separate out your library code (netstandard) from your application code (net 4.8 or net core).

Comment: This seems to be an XY Problem. You are solving the wrong problem here. .NET Core *can* run as a Windows Service. Just not in a .NET Framework Windows Service. Try asking how to create a Windows Service with .NET Core. That seems to be your real problem. You can have them in the same solution, just not referencing each other.